# easiest Automated testing tool in Java

Tags: junit, automated-tests

I want to learn quickly like in an few hours an automated testing tools.
Does somebody know any automated testing tool which is very easy and how can we do same automation in java. I want to use Junit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, JUnit is definitely your best bet for Java testing automation.  You can learn more about JUnit and even build a quick example application [here](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookbook/cookbook.htm).

Other tools to look at:

1. [Cactus](http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/)
2. [EasyMock](http://www.easymock.org/)
3. [Fit](http://fit.c2.com/)

Others that can be viewed [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/testing-tools).

Answer (score 0):

For preparing test dataset, consider [Beanmother](https://github.com/keepcosmos/beanmother)